# R studio: First time running tests with Dependent variables. Using lmer and nlme packages. Some questions

Tags: variables, lme4, nlme

I am trying to work with a dataset (see below). The Locality includes Rapsfeld and Bluhflache fields, which are not independent. I am setting SiteID as the random factor. I ran the test with both lmer and nlme packages, as this site explains: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_03.html. However, I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. Also, I've never used these tests before (only have experience with independent variable tests), so which values from which test would be most relevant for data analysis?

I'm just a little lost and definitely inexperienced, here is my code so far:

```
Input = ("
year    SiteID  Locality    SpeciesRichness SpeciesAbund
2016    3   Bluhflache  34  103
2016    9   Bluhflache  26  107
2016    12  Bluhflache  44  202
2016    13  Bluhflache  24  77
2016    14  Bluhflache  28  72
2016    27  Bluhflache  21  58
2016    29  Bluhflache  36  234
2016    37  Bluhflache  18  77
2016    39  Bluhflache  26  113
2016    56  Bluhflache  33  150
2016    61  Bluhflache  22  75
2016    62  Bluhflache  17  45
2017    3   Bluhflache  20  73
2017    3   Rapsfeld    21  131
2017    9   Bluhflache  12  40
2017    9   Rapsfeld    22  62
2017    12  Bluhflache  15  50
2017    12  Rapsfeld    18  126
2017    13  Bluhflache  16  181
2017    13  Rapsfeld    20  124
2017    27  Bluhflache  12  21
2017    27  Rapsfeld    21  220
2017    29  Bluhflache  27  164
2017    29  Rapsfeld    29  348
2017    32  Bluhflache  16  30
2017    37  Bluhflache  9   66
2017    37  Rapsfeld    5   40
2017    39  Bluhflache  18  97
2017    39  Rapsfeld    24  205
2017    67  Bluhflache  6   19
2017    67  Rapsfeld    21  108
")

SpeciesData = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)
```

## Each SiteID could be thought of has a block including a measurement for the Rapsfeld and a measurement for the Bluhflache. (is this correct??)

## Define model and conduct analysis of variance (with lmer)

```
library(lme4)

library(lmerTest)

model = lmer(SpeciesRichness ~ Locality + (1|SiteID), data=SpeciesData, REML=TRUE)
```

## 1|SiteID indicates that SiteID is the random term.

```
anova(model)
```

## output:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)
Locality 15.216  15.216     1 19.992  0.2355 0.6327
```

## Test the random effects in the model (with lmer)

## The rand function from the lmerTest package will test the random effects in the model.

```
rand(model)
```

## output for 1|SiteID:

```
ANOVA-like table for random-effects: Single term deletions

Model:
SpeciesRichness ~ Locality + (1 | SiteID)
             npar  logLik    AIC     LRT Df Pr(>Chisq)
<none>          4 -106.19 220.39                      
(1 | SiteID)    3 -106.44 218.89 0.50097  1     0.4791
```

## Mixed model with nlme:

## Define model and conduct analysis of deviance:

```
library(nlme)

model2 = lme(SpeciesRichness ~ Locality, random=~1|SiteID, data=SpeciesData, method="REML")

anova(model2)
```

## Output:

```
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    16 153.80039  <.0001
Locality        1    16   0.23553   0.634
```

## Test the random effects in the model

```
model.fixed = gls(SpeciesRichness ~ Locality, data=SpeciesData, method="REML")

anova(model2,
      model.fixed)
```

## output:

```
            Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test   L.Ratio
model2          1  4 220.3882 225.8574 -106.1941                 
model.fixed     2  3 218.8892 222.9911 -106.4446 1 vs 2 0.5009693
            p-value
model2             
model.fixed  0.4791
```